# h:commandbutton does not work in navbar

Tags: css, jsf

I'm really not getting why my `<h:commandbutton>` wont work.
If I put the same commandbutton outside of the navbar, it works. the button becomes white if I hover over it. My code is the following:

```
<nav class=" navbar nav-bottom"> 

    <img class="nav-item navbar-picture" src="#{resource['images/logo.gif']}" />
    <img class="nav-item nav-logo-text" src="#{resource['images/retailsonar.svg']}" />  

    <div class="topnav-right">
        <div style="float:left; margin-top:5px">
            <h:outputText class="navbar-text" id="welkom" value="Welkom, #{userBean.getNaam()}"/>
        </div>

        <div style="float:right">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton class="btn-navbar" action="#{userBean.logout()}" value="logout" />
            </h:form>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
<!-- navbar einde -->

<div class="vertical-center-full-page">
    <center class="vertical-center">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton class="btn-navbar" action="#{userBean.logout()}" value="logout" />
        </h:form>
```

the button in the navbar wont work
the button on the main screen does work, I can log out by clicking on it

Comment: Are you using any JS libraries here? Angular, perhaps? If so, please include tags for them in your question.

Comment: So when does it start working? When you remove the images? If not, please do..And try making it into a [mcve]. It helps you narrowing down the problem since it technically is not (ever) 'navbar' related (the commandButton does not know what a navbar is) but e.g. to the related css or javascript or... And 'not work' is not 'smart'. Is there an http call fired? Is there a response? Etc... That is what a developer should investigate